# Popping in a UINavigationController inside a UISplitViewController causes strange transition

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using a `UINavigationController` inside the Master View of a `UISplitViewController`.  Inside of my `UINavigationController` I have, as usual, a `UITableViewController`.  Selecting a cell in this table view pushes a new `UINavigationItem` onto the stack.  This transition occurs as I expect.  However, once I've pushed, when I push the Back button, the transition back to the top `UINavigationItem` doesn't slide from left to right as usual.  Instead, the screen goes black, the Master View holding the `UINavigationController`/`UITableViewController` slides down in the center of the screen from the top, and then the UINavigationController appears back on the left side where I expect it.  I've found similar questions, but all of the accepted answers revolve around not handling rotation correctly.  I've double-checked that all of my view controllers return `YES` for all orientations.

Comment: Implementing the orientation in the `UITableViewController` which I use in the `UINavigationViewController` correctly (returning YES on iPad) solved the problem for me.

Comment: I wish I could.  I never got a response and moved on since then, and can't remember how I fixed things...

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205511/odd-splitview-navigationcontroller-behavior-in-ios6/14580539

Answer (score 1):

implementing the following in my view controllers solved it for me

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Hope it works for you as well

Answer (score 0):

You should check your implementation of `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation` method in view controller that you have pushed into UINavigationController.

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
    {
     // should return YES for all orientations
     // or at least for orientation that your UINavigationController supports.
    }
```

For me this issue appears only on iOS 5, but if you experience it on iOS 6 also, you could implement `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` in similar way.

I hope it will help you.