# Odd SplitView/NavigationController behavior in iOS6

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

This is a long shot but I figured I'd see if anybody else has seen/fixed this issue.

I have an pre-IOS 6 app that uses a `UISplitViewController` with `NavigationControllers` in both the master and detail pane.

In iOS 5 and earlier, if I push a `UIViewController` onto the master navigation controller, it slides in; popping that view controller then slides it back out.

In iOS 6, in landscape orientation only, if I push a `UIViewController` onto the master navigation controller it slides in; however, popping that view controller then appears to consider the viewcontroller modal because it centers the view controller in the screen and then drops it to the bottom like a "`dismissModalController`" command would do. If it is in portrait mode, it slides in/out as expected.

I'm not sure what to do about this - Newer apps with similar layouts don't have this problem.  I suspect it has something to do with the initial window/navigator setup which (in this app) was configured the old way with `MainWindow.xib` and `MainWindow-iPad.xib`.   I'd rather not try to rip all that out and reconfigure using the "new" way (which does it all in the `appdelegate`)

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

implementing the following in my view controllers solved it for me

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Hope it works for you as well

Comment: yep, that was it.  I was using MaskPortrait for iPhone and I guess that caused issues on the iPad.  Thanks.